# Transfered SSL Certificate to Rackspace Cloud Server - Occasional Error

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, lamp

Okay, I recently tranfered my Comodo SSL certificate from my previous Bluehost account to my new rackspace cloud server. (LAMP stack)

Basically I just copy pasted the server cert and key and checked to make sure it was properly installed which it was. Now I am running into some issues, occasionally I will hear from people that they are getting an 'Untrusted Connection Error' while others are not getting this error at all.

Recently someone sent me a screen shot of their error and it said: This Certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided.

The browser they noticed this on was safari so I cleared all my history data in safari and opened the site but I am not seeing that error.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix something like this? Thanks!

When I enter openssl s_client... i get:

```
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Hosted by BlueHost.Com, INC/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=www.sitename.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=PositiveSSL CA 2
 1 s:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
 2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=PositiveSSL CA 2
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely lack the 'chain' or inter mediate certificates (which some people may have in their browser, and some not).

The easiest way to resolve this is by looking at the issuer details on your certificate; and finding that certificate. Then look at the issuer details of that cert - until you hit the 'root' - which is a self signed certificate (subject identical to issuer).

Once you've got them all concatenate them in a file and point SSLCertificateChainFile at that.

Your httpd.conf then looks like

```
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateKeyFile    .../your-key.key
   SSLCertificateFile       .../your-cert.pem
   SSLCertificateChainFile  .../ca-bundle.pem
```

Some CA's make this file available as a 'ca-bundle' (https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1203) when they issue a cert. Most don't.

So in that case you'll need to create it. Doing

```
openssl x509 -in <your cert.pem> -noout -issuer
```

will get you the exact issuer string. Googling for it generally gives you the intermediate cert you need (usually at the support site of your CA). Once you have that - repeat above and keep going at it until you are at the final one -- where issuer is identical to subject.

Once done - restart the webserver and that should be it.

If you want to verify you got the whole chain - then use the command

```
openssl s_client -connect <your domain name>:443
```

and check that the output starts with:

```
0 s:/C=GB/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=<your domain>
  i:/C=BE/O=Comodo/CN=Comodo foobar
....
3 s:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
  i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
```

and at least has one entry (3 in above example) where you have a final root; the S is identical top the i. If you just see a single entry

```
0 s:/C=GB/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=<your domain>
  i:/C=BE/O=Comodo/CN=Comodo foobar
```

and nothing more - then check your chain again - and make sure that it contains a cert with a *subject* identical to your *issuer* (in above example '/C=BE/O=Comodo/CN=Comodo foobar').

You can check this by parsing each blob in your bundle with

```
 openssl x509 -noout -in file.pem -subject -issuer
```

where file.pem is one chunk of your SSLCertificateChainFile file.

Caveat: Above is a slight simplification - some Chains may have multiple roots/cross-signing. In that case it gets a bit more complex - but follows above example.

Comment: Hi Dirk, I had a bundle file that was at bluehost...(.cabundle) I put it in with the cert and liked it in apache and ran your command, I got Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Hosted by BlueHost.Com, INC/OU=PositiveSSL/  CN=www.site.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=PositiveSSL CA

Comment: In that transaction there is also a part that says: Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
This worries me along with the fact that it says hosted by bluehost when that is no longer the case

Comment: Also, http://www.digicert.com/help/ shows the chain from the bundle but it shows a broken link between each cert

Comment: Ok - so you are getting somewhere. We just need to find out where the 'break' is. Try the "openssl s_client ..." command. That should help you see the entire chain. You can then check it for breaks/missing certs. These needs to be added to the bundle. And you need to check that the first CN=<yourdomain.com> matches *exactly* the domain name you are using and have configured.

Comment: Two things: when you say teh CN= exactly my domain name does that come all the way down to the absence of '.www' ?  Also, when I openssl I get a 'verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain' I don't see how this is possible since all these certs came from Bluehost/Comodo

Comment: I have edited the question to show the results of connecting to openssl

Comment: Right. So from that we learn two things - 1) your site name should be exactly 'www.sitename.com'. So https://www.sitename.com/ should go to it. (And not https://sitename.com/ or anything like that. Exactly https://www.sitename.com/. And secondly we see a valid chain going from that name (www.sitename.com) up to a self signed cert (though the order is swapped between 2 and 3). Some clients (android and java for example) are sensitive to the ordering - so I would swap them. So with this you should NO longer get anyone reporting an error to you around 'invalid chain'. However....

Comment: ... you may get some untrusted warning still from people who do not yet have the 'AddTrust External CA Root' hardcoded in their browser (I believe it was renewed as recent as January 2012 this year). So that is pretty much the best you can do. And these people can add the root to their browser - as they will have this issue at other sites as well.

Comment: You da MAN! Thanks for all your help, once I changed the cert order everything works perfectly!